# XSLT/Xpath: Why is it not possible to use the shortened notation for parent for the use attribute of the key function

Tags: xslt, xpath

It seems that it is not possible to use the shortened notation for `parent` for the `use` attribute of the `key` function, at least for my setup.

This does not work

```
<xsl:key name="eventsSuppressedByTheSameEventKey" match="suppressedMonitor" use="../suppressingMonitor/@event" />
```

But this does work

```
<xsl:key name="eventsSuppressedByTheSameEventKey" match="suppressedMonitor" use="parent::suppressingMonitor/@event" />
```

Why? Is the shortened notation not supported inside the `use` attribute for any reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short for:

```
parent::suppressingMonitor/@event
```

is:

```
../@event
```

not:

```
../suppressingMonitor/@event
```

Comment: Where did 'suppressingMonitor' go in the query?

Comment: @user2864740 Not sure what your question is.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  Would it be true to say that "parent::suppressingMonitor/@event" is in reality "../*[local-name()='suppressingMonitor']/@event", while "../@event" really is "../*/@event"?

Comment: `..` is short for `parent::node()`. This was my silly mistake

Comment: @Sebastien No. The abbreviated syntax for `parent::suppressingMonitor` is `..`. The path `../*` selects **children** of the parent node (the context node and its siblings). The path `../*/@event` selects the attributes of the context node and its siblings. OP wants to select an attribute of the parent, and that's `../@event`.